# How to filter SQL join to records that have multiple matches only

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

Consider a scenario where users can have multiple roles with different organisations.

The tables are:

*USER* - has an Id column
*ORGANISATION* - has an Id column
*ROLE* - has an Id column
*USERROLE* - has a User_Id column, an Organisation_Id column and a Role_Id column

*(So for example, User Bob can have roles 1, 2 and 3 with ABC Inc and role 1 with XYZ Plc)*

How do you only return users who have roles 1, 2 **and** 3? I don't mind if they have other roles as well or multiples of 1,  2 or 3 but they must at least have 1 of each role 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Select rows that match multiple rows in related table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23509404/mysql-select-rows-that-match-multiple-rows-in-related-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it doesn't matter in which company they have those roles, then this should do:

```
SELECT [User_Id] 
FROM USERROLE UR
WHERE Role_Id IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY [User_Id] 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Role_Id) = 3
```

Comment: Bingo! Exactly what I was after.